# How Junit configured in Jenkins through Jenkins Docker file

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

Hi i am trying to configure Junit on Jenkins Kubernetes using script

```
stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh './gradlew build'
            }
        }
        stage('Junit') {
            steps {
                sh './gradlew check'
            }
        }
```

But facing issue ./gradlew: not found can some one suggest how to achieve

Comment: Are you sure that Gradle wrapper is configured and committed?

Comment: Not Sure .is there any other way to achieve Junit , i don't want to install plugin and do manually.

Comment: You said: "./gradlew: not found" - are you sure that it's present in Jenkins env? Do you commit it? If not - then the reason is obvious. If you know the reason - you can resolve it.

Comment: I don't have full right to check in jenkins other wise why do i ask in this forum .

Comment: When you push your changes to repository, Jenkins (invoked using webhook for example) pulls latest changes and runs pipeline code in your projects directory. If you committed gradlew related files - then they will appear in Jenkins env. either. You don't need to have an access to Jenkins to check your repository and see if gradlew related files are committed to it. If they are not - then you have to commit them either, in order to use gradlew later.